# ECR2 push to ecr repository does not work

Tags: amazon-ecr

I created a new repository and i am trying to push an image. I just copy past the push commands:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 12345896.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

but i get the error:
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
and
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device

This is strange, because i just execute the standard commands which are suggested by aws.

Comment: Just faced the same issue, even though it was working fine inside CI procedure for a long time, Did you find any solution by a chance?

Comment: I am not sure, but if it is in the CI procedure, you would need to setup aws cli in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99.9% that the cause is AWS CLI version.

`get-login-password` was introduced in AWS CLI v1.17.10, thus any earlier version does not support it and returns "Invalid choice" error.